# Possibility of Windows App (that interact with Hardware connected via USB) be hosted in Windows Azure

Tags: windows, azure, cloud

Our application (which is a Windows App) basically uploads data into database and then other part of the application will take that data and send it to the hardware (which is connected to the PC throug USB Ports). So, will even this kind of applications are well suited for WINDOWS AZURE compliant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would not have any issues with the Database. However I am not aware of any way to connect an external device to a Windows Azure host. You do not have physical access to the data center.

So, unless you have some kind of protocol that can route your external devices' protocol (connected to local PC) to the Windows Azure Host (possibly using [Windows Azure Connect](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/tour/virtual-network/)), you can't fully port your application into Windows Azure.

One feasible way of doing what you want, is what I mentioned - a hybrid application:

- Will have one application that will run in Azure, process data to and from database (SQL Azure or Azure Table Storage). When it comes to sending data to an external device, it will send the data to a service which will run on:
- An on-premise application. This application will run locally and expose service endpoint to recieve request from the Azure application, and will route that data to the locally connected device.

Answer (score 0):

We have implemented soemthing like this (with USB barcode scanner, Mag stripe reader and printer) using a click-once application that connects back to Azure. This is probably the type of Hybrid approach that is described in the original answer.

Another posible approach would be to use a USB redirection application. This answer is theoretical only (I've not tried it). But, in theory you should be able to create a network connection between an on-premise machine (to which you connect the USB device) and the Windows Azure instance. You could then use a network USB redirector to remap the cloud USB port to the local one (http://www.net-usb.com/usb-redirector/)

As I said, highly theoretical and not really an apporach I would *recommend*. But, it is at least an option worth considering.

Comment: Thanks Chris, will look into this approach.